# ScrollViewer ChangeView - AccessViolationException one out of the thousand times

Tags: windows-runtime

I have FlipView (it's virtualized with `Mode="Standard"`) with ScrollViewer, Image (inside ScrollViewer as DataTemplate). I set `ImageOpened` event handler on Image with such code:

```cs
private void Image_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;

    double width = image.ActualWidth;
    double height = image.ActualHeight;
    var sv = image.Parent as ScrollViewer;

    if (sv != null && width != 0 && height != 0)
    {
        var properZoom = ZoomUtilities.CalculateZoomFactor(width, height);
        sv.MinZoomFactor = 0.3f;
        sv.ChangeView(null, null, properZoom);
        sv.MinZoomFactor = properZoom;                
    }
}
```

`properZoom` is always correct value. One out of the thousand times when I change item (swipe) or load page with this FlipView application crash with breakpoint on `sv.ChangeView(..)` and `AccessViolationException` exception is thrown. Does anyone know what could be the reason of such behaviour? Are there any restriction when I can call `ChangeView` method?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention - there is also `DoubleTapped` event handler on ScrollViewer which also calls `ChangeView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same AccessViolationException using `.ChangeView(..)`. I noticed the exception was thrown when the ScrollViewer I wanted to manipulate had focus. For example when a user was dragging through the list or controlling the scrollbar with his mouse.

*Disabling animations solved my problems*. If you want to keep the animations you should look for a way to remove focus on the controls before changing the view. I guess the animated ChangeView tries to change a property that is locked because of the user input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the [ChangeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn252763.aspx) function takes a parameter to disable/ enable animations. I believe that is what is discussed in the 2nd paragraph of this answer but am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Solution to me: call inverse, from image object to parent got error.
Call normal path: objectscroolviewer.changeview, works no error.
Then:

```
var sv = image.Parent as ScrollViewer;
```

change to

```
var sv = ScrollViewerObject;
```

Get object to variable externally, not by internal reference of parent, and ignores sender parameter.